# How do I avoid background translation at LinearLayout when I press on EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have LinearLayout with gradient `<gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#3300FF00" android:centerColor="#00F4F98A" android:startColor="#CCFA3362" android:type="linear"  />`. When I press on EditText, background translates. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` in your Manifest to your activity, or set background gradient to your window view. Just place

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()
```

in your activity